# Access cell alignment in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

As it can be tested in the [align cell demo](http://handsontable.com/demo/align_cell.html), handsontable supports cell alignment:

- Horizontal

  - Left
  - Center
  - Right
  - Justify
- Vertical

  - Top
  - Middle
  - Bottom

Here a screenshot:

[image: handsontable screenshot]

I can access the data with:

```
$('#table-wrapper').handsontable('getData')
```

But how can I access the cell alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. There is a [cell method](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Methods#cell-methods) called `getCellMeta`. It returns an array containing an `className` entry.

It can be accessed:

```
var cellMeta = $('#table-wrapper').handsontable('getCellMeta', 0, 0);
var className = cellMeta['className']; //String containing the information.
```

Values are:

- Horizontal

  - Left: `htLeft`
  - Center: `htCenter`
  - Right: `htRight`
  - Justify: `htJustify`
- Vertical

  - Top: `htTop`
  - Middle: `htMiddle`
  - Bottom: `htBottom`

Of course you can have a combination of two values (for horizontal and vertical) separated with a space.